# collection view cell changing display order among with other cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[image: Collection view cell design]

I added cells in collection view each have different cell identifiers.
But each cell type can access more then one.

Cell order will come depend on data if cell 5 data comes first cell5 has to show like wise all.

Here sometimes only one cell is changing it's position.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtindexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let valueLabels = Array(valuesPidMap.keys)[indexPath.row]
    let pidinfo = self.getsettingsName(pid: valueLabels)

    if valueLabels == constants1 {
        return cell2
    }

    if valueLabels == constants2 {
        return cell3
    }

    if valueLabels == constants3 {
        return cell4
    }

    if valueLabels == constants4{
        return cell5
    }

   //for all other constants
   // other cell dat objects will come here i will get more then one


    return cell
}
```

Comment: `Array(valuesPidMap.keys)`. A `Dictionary` is unordered, and its property `keys` shouldn't guarantee the same order each time it's called.

Comment: so what should i do to not change order?

Comment: I added Sorting logic on Array(valuesPidMap.keys) and then displayed .. Any how Thanks for the help .